# Fast pandas.DataFrame initialization

Tags: python, pandas

## Question

What is an efficient way to get the following pandas DataFrame? (Update: numbers change each time)

```
   alpha  beta  gamma
0    1.5   2.5    3.5

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

### Motivation

I added a pandas.DataFrame API to some of my methods be able to do calculations in batches.

When replicating some of my testcases for the new API the execution of my testbenches raised from 200ms to over 8 seconds. Doing a profile run, I noticed that the main cause is creating 20k `pandas.DataFrame` objects.

See the comparison

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: timeit pd.DataFrame({'alpha': 1.5, 'beta': 2.5, 'gamma': 3.5}, [0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 405 us per loop

In [3]: timeit {'alpha': 1.5, 'beta': 2.5, 'gamma': 3.5}
1000000 loops, best of 3: 200 ns per loop
```

It seems that creating a DataFrame object is 2000 times slower than lower level structures. I tried to optimize it, but this is as fast as I got:

```
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: timeit pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]]), columns=['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 144 us per loop
```

This is still 720 times slower than the dict. Is it possible to be faster? Creating numpy arrays is e.g. only 10 times slower:

```
In [6]: timeit np.array([[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]])
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.99 us per loop
```

Comment: what are you actually going to do with the frame? you are creating a rich data structure. if u are simply creating a 1 row multi-column frame then u should just make a dict.

Comment: I have written tests for some numeric functions. In such tests 1000 different parameters are tested based on a csv file. The problem with many pandas objects is more of a problem during testing the new API, rather than in normal usage. There these numeric functions will only be called a few times, with big DataFrames. My goal is to keep tests below 1s, otherwise I won't be able to execute them constantly.

Comment: so what is the point of your 'benchmark' if it's not realistic? you should test a realistic example of what you are doing

Comment: I am not after a benchmark, I want to writing fast unittests. To get good coverage, tests mostly cover corner cases.

Comment: that's a nice goal but using a 1 row frame is not useful IMHO. you would not in real life create 20k different frames that would defeat the purpose of using pandas. if it causes your test suite to take 8s but provides a lot of additional functionality what is the problem? yes pandas objects have some amount of overhead to create. they are not dicts nor are they numpy arrays; if u want those then use them.

Comment: Thank you very much for that comparison. I think a lot of people coming to DataFrames think that they are near-equally fast as numpy operations.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a global data frame for your tests and just do `df = global_df.copy()`, example:

```
In[1] global_df = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': 1.5, 'beta': 2.5, 'gamma': 3.5}, [0])
In[2] timeit global_df.copy()
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.2 us per loop
```

Comment: Neat! I just did a test, unfortunately I have to change the numbers in each iteration. On my machine it results in `In [1]: timeit local_df = global_df.copy(); local_df.loc[0] = 1.3, 2.3, 3.3
1000 loops, best of 3: 207 us per loop`. This is even slower than the numpy version.